# How to create program from netstat command in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

hi i want to make program which gives netstat information in vc++. like for command which gives information about MySQL Port, and for IIS Port

netstat -aon | findstr 3306, netstat -aon | findstr 80

by using this commands how should i write program for vc++.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the system function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/